# PIL thinks every image I give it is corrupted

Tags: python-imaging-library, truncated

I'm trying to get an array of RGB values for a jpeg.  Using the code

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('lion.jpg')
pix = list(im.getdata())
```

gives the error

```
IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

The picture in the code is this one, which I got from google for testing:
[image: a lion]

but the code returns the same error for every picture I've tried, from a variety of sources (google, phone, etc...).  When I push forward and load the image anyway, all the pixel values are black.

I've tried doing

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

but all that does is suppress the error; the pixel values are still black.

It seems other people have had this problem elsewhere, like [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1510), but so far other solutions have failed me.  Any suggestions?

I'm on Mac 10.10, with python 2.7.8. I first installed Pillow with `pip`, and then from the source.  I have confirmed that `libjpeg` is installed.

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using Python 2.7? Did `pip install Pillow` give any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an answer, but I can give you the setup of mine for which this is working fine.

The following script:

```
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = Image.open('lion.jpg'))
    pix = list(im.getdata())
    print('The image has {} pixels'.format(len(pix)))

    import PIL, sys
    print('Using Python version {}'.format(sys.version))
    print('Using PIL version {}'.format(PIL.VERSION))
    print('Using Pillow version {}'.format(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION))
```

Gives as a result on my Macbook with OS X El Capitan (10.11.6):

```
The image has 1183000 pixels
Using Python version 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
Using PIL version 1.1.7
Using Pillow version 3.1.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```